# How do I install these PHP extensions on Ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

- Ubuntu 16.04.
- nginx version: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
- PHP 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3

When I run `composer install -v` in Magento 2 directory I get this:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Dependency resolution completed in 0.000 seconds
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-gd * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
  Problem 2
    - The requested PHP extension ext-dom * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's dom extension.
  Problem 3
    - The requested PHP extension ext-simplexml * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's simplexml extension.
  Problem 4
    - The requested PHP extension ext-mcrypt * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mcrypt extension.
  Problem 5
    - The requested PHP extension ext-curl * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's curl extension.
  Problem 6
    - The requested PHP extension ext-intl * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
  Problem 7
    - The requested PHP extension ext-xsl * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's xsl extension.
  Problem 8
    - The requested PHP extension ext-mbstring * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mbstring extension.
  Problem 9
    - The requested PHP extension ext-zip * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's zip extension.
  Problem 10
    - Installation request for braintree/braintree_php 3.7.0 -> satisfiable by braintree/braintree_php[3.7.0].
    - braintree/braintree_php 3.7.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
  Problem 11
    - Installation request for pelago/emogrifier v0.1.1 -> satisfiable by pelago/emogrifier[v0.1.1].
    - pelago/emogrifier v0.1.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP extension mbstring is missing from your system.
  Problem 12
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 4.1.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[4.1.0].
    - phpunit/phpunit 4.1.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 13
    - Installation request for theseer/fdomdocument 1.6.1 -> satisfiable by theseer/fdomdocument[1.6.1].
    - theseer/fdomdocument 1.6.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
  Problem 14
    - theseer/fdomdocument 1.6.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    - sebastian/phpcpd 2.0.0 requires theseer/fdomdocument ~1.4 -> satisfiable by theseer/fdomdocument[1.6.1].
    - Installation request for sebastian/phpcpd 2.0.0 -> satisfiable by sebastian/phpcpd[2.0.0].
```

How do I install these extensions? I have LEMP stack installed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Installing PHP extensions is widely documented

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/74717389/15770919

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can most probably use your package manager to do this. 
For the gd extension specifically you can run

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```

And there is probably a similar package for the rest of the extensions available. 
with apt-cache search you can search for packages. for example

```
 apt-cache search php7.0
```

will find you all packages related to php7.0