# How to deploy a Laravel app to a digital ocean database and server?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, digital-ocean

I set up a server and database on Digital Ocean using [Ploi.io](https://ploi.io/). Ploi sent me an email that my server was created with the following info:

```
Server IP: 111.111.111.11
User: myUsername
Sudo password: XXXXXXXXXX

Database user: myUsername
Database password: XXXXXXXXX
```

I left out the real credentials. When I log in to Digital Ocean I confirm that my droplet was created.

[image: droplet created on digital ocean]

I've created a Laravel app and database on my local machine. How do I push my Laravel 5.6 app to this server and database?

Comment: Are you using git?

Comment: can you login to the server through the ssh ?

Comment: Yes I am using git and github. I added my ssh keys to ploi, not sure how I'd ssh into the server though

Comment: well simple way to say this you have to login to the your droplet and using git you have to clone your project into your droplet. idk what  ploi  is. but my recommendation is to use docker

Comment: You can get help from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40815984/how-to-install-all-required-php-extensions-for-laravel/66741944#66741944

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already replied to your e-mail, but I will clarify here as well.

You can SSH into the server with the 'ploi' user (ssh ploi@{IP}), with your SSH key added, you will automatically be granted access to your server.

To install a app on your server with Ploi, you can either use: github, gitlab, bitbucket or SFTP to upload your project.

You can add a website in ploi where you can install your project.

Comment: Ahh you can connect through the UI and a deployment script will display! Very cool thank you. Tutorial here: https://medium.com/@connorleech/deploy-a-laravel-5-app-using-ploi-and-digital-ocean-1d27929d9516