# Getting error for connecting sybase with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Below error, I'm getting while accessing web service call via postman Sybase DB,

> Call to undefined function Abram\Odbc\odbc_connect()

Below configuration I applied;

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "abram/laravel-odbc": "dev-master",
    "agomez/laravel-odbc-driver": "^1.0",
     }
```

**database.php**

```
 'sybase' => [
        'driver' => 'odbc',
        'dsn'  => '*****',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST','*****'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT','*****'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install all required PHP extensions for Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40815984/how-to-install-all-required-php-extensions-for-laravel)

Comment: still getting same error. I applied command which described link. and I restarted xampp also. @emix

Comment: It will work when you install the `odbc` extension.

Comment: how can I check if odbc installed or not and if not then how can I install it in linux @emix

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=php+how+install+odbc+extension

Comment: I did all these things and installed odbc. but still getting same error. what I have to do after installing odbc? @emix

Comment: Ask another question how to install and enable an extension properly in Xampp.

Comment: write your answer in this question I will upvote and edit my question @emix