# using laravel 9 and the command composer create-project laravel/laravel projectname i am getting the following issue

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, laravel

C:\xampp\htdocs>composer create-project laravel/laravel chirper
Creating a "laravel/laravel" project at "./chirper"
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Installing laravel/laravel (v9.5.1)
Failed to download laravel/laravel from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
Now trying to download from source

- Syncing laravel/laravel (v9.5.1) into cache
- Installing laravel/laravel (v9.5.1): Cloning 5c7cc8eee4 from cache
  Created project in C:\xampp\htdocs\chirper

> @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies
> Lock file operations: 106 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

- Locking brick/math (0.10.2)
- Locking dflydev/dot-access-data (v3.0.2)
- Locking doctrine/inflector (2.0.6)
- Locking doctrine/instantiator (2.0.0)
- Locking doctrine/lexer (3.0.0)
- Locking dragonmantank/cron-expression (v3.3.2)
- Locking egulias/email-validator (4.0.1)
- Locking fakerphp/faker (v1.21.0)
- Syncing laravel/sail (v1.18.1) into cache
  Failed to download laravel/sanctum from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing laravel/sanctum (v3.2.1) into cache
  Failed to download nikic/php-parser from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing nikic/php-parser (v4.15.3) into cache
  Failed to download psy/psysh from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing psy/psysh (v0.11.11) into cache
  Failed to download laravel/tinker from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing laravel/tinker (v2.8.0) into cache
  Failed to download hamcrest/hamcrest-php from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing hamcrest/hamcrest-php (v2.0.1) into cache
  Failed to download mockery/mockery from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing mockery/mockery (1.5.1) into cache
  Failed to download filp/whoops from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing filp/whoops (2.14.6) into cache
  Failed to download nunomaduro/collision from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing nunomaduro/collision (v6.4.0) into cache
  Failed to download sebastian/version from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing sebastian/version (3.0.2) into cache
  Failed to download sebastian/type from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing sebastian/type (3.2.0) into cache
  Failed to download sebastian/resource-operations from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing sebastian/resource-operations (3.0.3) into cache
  Failed to download sebastian/recursion-context from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing sebastian/recursion-context (4.0.4) into cache
  Failed to download sebastian/object-reflector from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing sebastian/object-reflector (2.0.4) into cache
  Failed to download sebastian/object-enumerator from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing sebastian/object-enumerator (4.0.4) into cache
  Failed to download sebastian/global-state from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing sebastian/global-state (5.0.5) into cache
  Failed to download sebastian/exporter from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing sebastian/exporter (4.0.5) into cache
  Failed to download sebastian/environment from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source
- Syncing sebastian/environment (5.1.4) into cache
  Failed to download sebastian/diff from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both text-template (2.0.4): Cloning 5da5f67fc9 from cache
- Installing phpunit/php-invoker (3.1.1): Cloning 5a10147d0a from cache
- Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (3.0.6): Cloning cf1c2e7c20 from cache
- Installing theseer/tokenizer (1.2.1): Cloning 34a41e998c from cache
- Installing sebastian/lines-of-code (1.0.3): Cloning c1c2e997aa from cache
- Installing sebastian/complexity (2.0.2): Cloning 739b35e533 from cache
- Installing sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup (2.0.3): Cloning ac91f01cce from cache
- Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (9.2.23): Cloning 9f1f0f9a2f from cache
- Installing phar-io/version (3.2.1): Cloning 4f7fd7836c from cache
- Installing phar-io/manifest (2.0.3): Cloning 97803eca37 from cache
- Installing myclabs/deep-copy (1.11.0): Cloning 14daed4296 from cache
- Installing doctrine/instantiator (2.0.0): Cloning c6222283fa from cache
- Installing phpunit/phpunit (9.5.28): Cloning 954ca3113a from cache
- Installing spatie/backtrace (1.2.1): Cloning 4ee7d41aa5 from cache
- Installing spatie/flare-client-php (1.3.5): Cloning 3e5dd5ac49 from cache
- Installing spatie/ignition (1.4.3): Cloning 2cf3833220 from cache
- Installing spatie/laravel-ignition (1.6.4): Cloning 1a2b4bd3d4 from cache
  72 package suggestions were added by new dependencies, use `composer suggest` to see details.
  Generating optimized autoload files
  Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "App\Providers\AppServiceProvider" was found in both "C:/xampp/htdocs/chirper/app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php" and "C:/xampp/htdocs/chirper/vendor/laravel/pint/app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php", the first will be used.

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

INFO  Discovering packages.

laravel/sail ................................................................................................................................ DONE
laravel/sanctum ............................................................................................................................. DONE
laravel/tinker .............................................................................................................................. DONE
nesbot/carbon ............................................................................................................................... DONE
nunomaduro/collision ........................................................................................................................ DONE
nunomaduro/termwind ......................................................................................................................... DONE
spatie/laravel-ignition ..................................................................................................................... DONE

80 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

> @php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force

INFO  No publishable resources for tag [laravel-assets].

No security vulnerability advisories found
Do you want to remove the existing VCS (.git, .svn..) history? [Y,n]?

**i am getting the following issue once i run the command , however the project is creating but i want to know why the problem occurs .**

Answer (score 0):

I think the zip extension is not installed in your system.

You can use the following command in Ubuntu to check the necessary extensions.

Installation specific to a particular version of PHP (such as PHP 8.2)

```html
sudo apt install php8.2-zip
```

You can check the post : [Install PHP extensions for laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40815984/how-to-install-all-required-php-extensions-for-laravel)